# In ggplot2, what is the replacement method for the aes_string() function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After updating the ggplot2 package, I received a warning message when running code that includes `aes_string`: "aes_string() was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0." Now, I am trying to replace this function in my original code, but I have not found a satisfactory solution yet.

In the simplified example below, I need to use three variables to map x, y, and color categories. The color category may or may not exist, and using `aes_string` solved this problem perfectly. However, using `aes` creates more complications.

I have referred to some online examples and have summarized four methods below, but they will not work if the color category does not exist. So, are there any other methods that can perfectly replace `aes_string`?

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- "displ"
b <- "hwy"
d <- "drv"
d <- c()

# aes_string(), it works perfectly even when `d <- c()`
ggplot(mpg, aes_string(a,b, color=d))+
  geom_point()

# The following codes can produce the same plot when `d <- "drv"`,
#   but none of them can run when `d <- c()`.
# 1.aes()+get()+
ggplot(mpg, aes(get(a), get(b), color=get(d)))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=a, y=b)+
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=d))
# 2.aes()+!!sym()
ggplot(mpg, aes(!!sym(a), !!sym(b), color=!!sym(d)))+
  geom_point()
# 3.aes()+str2expression()+eval()
ggplot(mpg, aes(eval(str2expression(a)), eval(str2expression(b)), color=eval(str2expression(d))))+
  geom_point()+
  labs(x=a, y=b)+
  guides(color=guide_legend(title=d))
# 4.aes()+.data[[]]
ggplot(mpg)+
  geom_point(aes(.data[[a]], .data[[b]], color=.data[[d]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the same behaviour as `aes_string`, in that a `NULL` value passed to the aesthetics is interpreted as `NULL`, rather than leading to an error as the other methods do.

That being the case, we can do

```r
library(ggplot2)

a <- "displ"
b <- "hwy"
d <- "drv"

ggplot(mpg, 
       aes(x = .data[[a]], y = .data[[b]], 
           color = if(is.null(d)) NULL else .data[[d]])) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(color = d)
```

[image]

Now repeat the exact same code but with `d <- c()` (i.e. `d` being `NULL`)

```
d <- c()

ggplot(mpg, 
       aes(x = .data[[a]], y = .data[[b]], 
           color = if(is.null(d)) NULL else .data[[d]])) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(color = d)
```

[image]

Comment: I was just trying to get this working per your comment above using `ifelse()` which failed FYI! +1

Comment: Thank you so much. You have solved my problem exactly, and I have just learned that a conditional statement can be used there.

Answer (score 4):

Use `.data` . Note that the default `else` leg is `NULL` so if `d` is `NULL`, `c()` or any zero length object the color aesthetic will be `NULL` and otherwise it will be `.data[[d]]`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

d <- NULL    
BOD %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = .data[["Time"]], 
             y = .data[["demand"]], 
             col = if (length(d)) .data[[d]])) + 
    geom_line()
```

Comment: Thank you, your code is shorter, which is very useful.

Answer (score 3):

Per the help....`?aes_string()`

All these functions are soft-deprecated. Please use tidy evaluation idioms instead. Regarding aes_string(), you can replace it with .data pronoun. For example, the following code can achieve the same mapping as aes_string(x_var, y_var).

```
x_var <- "foo"
y_var <- "bar"
aes(.data[[x_var]], .data[[y_var]])
```

Including a NULL:

```
# Runs but singular color mapped?
ggplot(mpg, aes(.data[['displ']], .data[['hwy']],
 color=ifelse(is.null(d),NULL,.data[['drv']])))+
  geom_point()
```

See @AllenCameron comment and answer to solve this issue